# Show name of chosen fil inside upload form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms, file-upload

I want to show the selected filename and extension as seen on picture below.
All this takes place inside a HTML form.

[image: upload]

The best code that i have found for this purpose is this (also what i shown on picture):

```
<label for="uploaded_file">Vælg en fil:</label>
<input type="file" name="uploaded_file">
<p>Valgt fil:</p>
<?php
    if(isset($_FILES['uploaded_file']['name'])) {
        echo $_FILES['uploaded_file']['name']." was uploaded";
    }else{
        echo "No File Uploaded";
    }
?>
```

But this code doesn't show it. And ofcourse it doesn't because i haven't submitted the form yet. Also i have been looking for som jQuery/Javascript features, but i have found none that fit or could fit my purpose.

My whole intension is later on i will "upgrade" my upload form for upload of multiple files.

How can i make this script working?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the name of the uploaded file by grabbing the `input` off the DOM with javascript, and then accessing the `value` property. Note, the `input` must have the file already selected by the user, so in the example below I use a `<button>` click handler to check the `value`.

HTML:

```
<label for="uploaded_file">Vælg en fil:</label>
<input id="file" type="file" name="uploaded_file">
<p>Valgt fil:</p>

<button id="btn">Get File Name</button>
```

JavaScript:

```
var input = document.getElementById('file');

// Attach click handler to button.
document.getElementById('btn').addEventListener('click', function() {
    // Grab name of uploaded file (use the `value` property of the input element).
    alert(input.value);
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your fast answer. That truly works but it is note quite what i want with the extra button.

Comment: Don't use the extra button then :) I just put it there so you can test it out locally. Just grab the `value` of the `input` when you are ready to use it. The first paragraph is the answer, the code examples are just showing a way to reproduce it.

Comment: I can't recall how i can get around the push button :(

Comment: When do you need the name of the file?

Comment: When image have been selected in the "input type="file""

Answer (score 0):

By using on change event you can get the uploaded file name with extension. You can use either javascript or jquery. The below code is using javascript

```
<label for="uploaded_file">Vælg en fil:</label>
<input id="file" type="file" name="uploaded_file">
// added id for the tag to place the file name
<p id="file_name">Valgt fil:</p>

<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById('file').onchange = function() {
    var input = document.getElementById('file').files[0].name; 
    var p_tag = document.getElementById('file_name');
    p_tag.innerHTML = p_tag.innerHTML +' ' + input;
}

</script>
```